# MVC3 ActionResult does not reload page if client is already on it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public ActionResult DeleteCategory(int id)
{
     CategoryManager manager = new CategoryManager();
     manager.DeleteCategory(id);
     TempData["IsDeleted"] = true;
     return RedirectToAction("CategoriesList");
}

 public ActionResult CategoriesList()
 {
     List<CategoryModel> model = new CategoryManager().GetAll();
     return View(model);
 }

 public void DeleteCategory(int categoryId)
 {
     using (AsoEntities context = new AsoEntities())
     {
         var categoryToDelete = (from c in context.Categories 
            where c.Id == categoryId
            select c).SingleOrDefault();
         if (categoryToDelete == null)
            return;

         context.Categories.DeleteObject(categoryToDelete);
         context.SaveChanges();
     }
 }
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    // Dialog
    $('.delete-link').click(function () {
        deleteLinkObj = $(this); //for future use
        $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
        return false; // prevents the default behaviour
    });

    $('#delete-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true, //Dialog options
        buttons: {
            "Da": function () {
                $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) { //Post to action
                    if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {
                        deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('fast'); //Hide Row
                        //(optional) Display Confirmation
                    }
                    else {
                        //(optional) Display Error
                    }
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Ne": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I delete an article I am taken back to CategoriesList; but the page is not reloaded if I am already on CategoriesList.  How can I make it so that the page will be re-loaded and the data will be refreshed?

**Edit:**

If I remove the Javascript then it starts working.  Where is the problem in the Javscript?

Comment: on the delete category, is the action submitted to the database? can you check on sql?

Comment: yes it is deleted. If i use f5 deleted item dissapear.

Comment: well are you doing any caching? or it's a problem with your browser? can you test with another browser?

Comment: There seems to be code missing here. It doesn't seem to make sense. Is the third block supposed to be 'public ActionResult Delete(id)'?

Comment: Have you checked the http request and the http reponse with fiddler?

Comment: You must have to specifically tell it to refresh at some point then? Else It must be "intelligent" to think that you are already on the page, and not bother redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jquery to delete the item asynchronously which will mean that the page is not reloaded.

Your code has this line:  if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {  but in the server side method is not returning a bool so the above line will never equal true and so deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('fast'); //Hide Row is never called.